# Magento - Redirect account edit success

Tags: magento-1.9

When i edit my account information in "customer/account/edit", after submits it goes to my account page. I need the form to stay in same page after submitting and saving information. In my module config.xml i made a redirect:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_editPostAction>
            <observers>
              <customerredirect>
                <class>customerredirect/observer_customer</class>
                <method>editRedirect</method>
              </customerredirect>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_editPostAction>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Then in Model -> Observer -> Customer.php i have the function:

```
   public function editRedirect(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
      $url = Mage::getUrl('sales/order/history');
      Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
      return $this;
    }
```

If i change

> controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_editPostAction

into

> controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_edit

it redirects account edit page into sales history. But what i want to redirect is after form submits. I'm also trying to redirect my account inital page "customer/account" to "sales/order/history" page, but this method it's not working when i put controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to simply rewrite a `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`, `editPostAction()` in your local codePool, then change this :

```
...
try {
    $customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
    $customer->save();
    $this->_getSession()->setCustomer($customer)
         ->addSuccess($this->__('The account information has been saved.'));
    $this->_redirect('customer/account');
    return;
...
```

to:

```
...
    try {
        $customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
        $customer->save();
        $this->_getSession()->setCustomer($customer)
             ->addSuccess($this->__('The account information has been saved.'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/edit');
        return;
...
```

Then after submit, he save a new data and return the same page.

Comment: It's not working. I tried before editing the AccountController.php in app/code/local/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php but for some reason it doesn't redirect. It's like the file is being overriden by another file/extension. I already tried searching in plugins/modules without success.

Comment: Ah Ok, the solution works i tried it and i confirm, however if you have rewrited it, you have to find it in your app/code/local or community if  you have installed an extension.

Answer (score 0):

### `Why controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_editPostAction not worked`

In order to understand the why *`controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_editPostAction`* is not worked then You should check `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action`'s  at method [dispatch($action)](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L398)

In magento, there are all the events by application defined and  at  ***every page dispatch*** there are few events call automatically like

> Mage::dispatchEvent(
>                   'controller_action_postdispatch_'.$this->getFullActionName(),
>                   array('controller_action'=>$this)
>               );

As per as this logic,magento is create an event `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_edit`  on ***customer/account/edit***'s ***postdispatch()***.

The full Action name of this URL is `customer_account_edit` .`$this->getFullActionName()` give this ***fullaction Name of this url***.

As we know that ***customer/account/edit*** mean `routername/ActioName/Actionname`

- Route name is `customer` As **frontend** name **`customer`**
  `account`
- Controller file is `AccountController.php` that why Action name
  `account`
- Action Method is `editAction()` that why Action name `edit`

---

`controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_editPostAction`

So, it edit`accountinfo's`  event name is

`controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_editPost`

---

"`customer/account`"  is event name is

`controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_index`

Comment: This redirect worked. Only problem is keeping session messsages like success messages. BTW, thanks for the explanation. :)